Python Selenium - Get sibling link depending on inner text of span
I've been working on this for hours, but just can't seem to put all the parts together...
So given:
<a href="link1">link</a>
<span class="class_name">00A<span>
...
<a href="link2">link</a>
<span class="class_name">00B<span>
...
<a href="link3">link</a>
<span class="class_name">01B<span>
...
<a href="link4">link</a>
<span class="class_name">01A<span>

I'm trying to get the link depending on the inner text of span. So I know...
I can get all the links with:
links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'class_name')]//preceding-sibling::a[@href]")))]

I can get the text on a single span with:
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'class_name')]").text)

But I cant use find elements to get all of their text to test since it's asking for text of a list.
I should be able to use:
[contains(text(), '\\d+[A]')]")

But I don't know how to combine it with the code for all the links. I feel like I'm overlooking something really stupid but it's 6:30am and I started working on this project in the evening yesterday, so I give up and just going to ask someone more intelligent. Thank you in advance for any help.

you'd iterate over an array of webelement references (find_elements returns webelement reference array) and get either links from the span references, or spans from the link references.  (though not too sure I understood the question... maybe clarify what you want the end result to be? and/or what you are testing for)

I'll try that out once I get home, thank you. I'm trying to get the links depending what the span text is, ie get all the A's sibling links, and not any of the others like the Bs.

Note that the second parameter of the contains() function is not a regular expression; it's a plain string which is to be sought within the first string parameter. I believe with Selenium you are stuck with XPath 1.0 which does not have any regular expression functions.
Without using a regular expression, if you wanted to filter a set of span elements to include only those whose text content consisted of a string of digits followed by a single A, you would need to use a more complicated expression which combines a bunch of string functions, e.g. something like:
span[
   contains(., 'A') and
   contains('0123456789', substring(., 1, 1)) and 
   translate(substring-before(., 'A'), '0123456789', '') = '' and
   substring-after(., 'A') = ''
]

NB the . is a reference to the "context node" which in the predicate expression means one of the span elements.
This expression means:
span elements

which contain an A character somewhere; and
whose first character is a digit; and
the text before the A consists entirely of digits; and
where there's no text after the A (i.e. there's just one A, at the end)

BTW, I'm not sure this expression does what you think it does:
//span[contains(@class, 'class_name')]//preceding-sibling::a[@href]

To clarify: the // in XPath is an abbreviation for the expression /descendant-or-self::node()/. So your expression could be written as:
//span[contains(@class, 'class_name')]
   /descendant-or-self::node()/preceding-sibling::a[@href]

This will return every a element (with an href attribute) which is followed by a sibling element which is either:

a span element with a class attribute of 'class_name'; or
a descendant of a span element with a class attribute of 'class_name'.

If you know that the span and a are actually siblings then you can replace that // with the simpler / (and in my suggestion below).
The other thing to note here is that unless each pair of span (or span descendant) and a are contained with a parent element, then the preceding-sibling::a[@href] step will return all the a elements that precede the span, not just the first such span (which is I suspect what you want to do, in that I take it that it's the immediately preceding span that provides a label for the link. You can apply the predicate [1] to the set of a[@href] elements to get just the first (in preceding-sibling order).
So to combine these ideas, here's my suggestion:
//span
   [
      contains(@class, 'class_name') and
      contains(., 'A') and
      contains('0123456789', substring(., 1, 1)) and 
      translate(substring-before(., 'A'), '0123456789', '') = '' and
      substring-after(., 'A') = ''
   ]
   //preceding-sibling::a[@href][1]

Applied to this input:
<body>
  
<a href="link1">link</a>
<span class="class_name">00A</span>
...
<a href="link2">link</a>
<span class="class_name">00B</span>
...
<a href="link3">link</a>
<span class="class_name">01B</span>
...
<a href="link4">link</a>
<span class="class_name">01A</span>

</body>

... it yields:
<a href="link1">link</a>
<a href="link4">link</a>


Thank you for your help, but your suggestion was producing an empty list. I believe there's a problem somewhere in lines 3-5 within the brackets. However I was able to use the rest of it to figure it out.
for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'class_name'') and contains(text(), 'A')]//preceding-sibling::a[@href]"):
  print(element.get_attribute("href"))

Sorry I realized the reason for the empty list was a result of the line about the text after A and believe a space in the span. So
for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'class_name') and contains(., 'A') and contains('0123456789', substring(., 1, 1)) and translate(substring-before(., 'A'), '0123456789', '') = '']/preceding-sibling::a[@href]"):
  print(element.get_attribute("href"))

Is printing the same results. Thank you so much.
